# как преобразовать массив в объект в котором ключи будут равны значениям

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

есть такой массив, мне нужно сделать объект такого вида: {4:4, 6:6, 9:9, hello:"hello"}
я подумала, что для начала нужно просто весь массив преобразовать в объект, но не могу понять, как ключи сделать равными значениям

let arr = [4, 6, 9, 'hello'];

ler obj = {}

Object.assign(obj, arr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let arr = [4, 6, 9, 'hello'];

let obj = arr.reduce((a, i) => (a[i] = i, a), {});

console.log(obj);
```